# solve for $x$ without using softwares $\log_{\sqrt{x}}2+\log_6x^x=4$

Tags: logarithms

Is there any nice way to solve this equation without wolfram?

$\log_{\sqrt{x}}2+\log_6x^x=4$

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the source of the problem

Comment: @labbhattacharjee - it's a question i found in one of my old notebook of exersices no source known.

Comment: Since wolfram alpha doesn't find an exact solution, I don't think there are any such solutions, and thus it probably can't be solved in a 'nice' way.

Comment: It's equivalent to, with $t=\log_2 x$, 
$$ \log_62 \cdot t^2 2^t-4t+2=0$$ 
Unlikely to yield except to numerical methods.

Comment: @dave Then you probably copied it wrong, unless your question is meant to use the Lambert W-function, or if you only want an approximation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - i double cheaked. i guess they want an aproximation. thanks.

Comment: Using Goal Seek in EXCEL, you get a value of 1.455268598 which could be a fraction of some kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting $$\log_{\sqrt{x}}2+\log_6x^x=4$$ leads to the equation $$f(x)=x \log ^2(x)-4 \log (6) \log (x)+\log (4) \log (6)=0$$ which cannot be solved analytically ($f'(x)=0$ or $f''(x)=0$ cannot be solved either).

Plotting the function shows two roots, the first close to $x=1.5$, the second close to $x=4.0$. For the solution, Newton is the simplest root-finder. Strating from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$, it will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

For the first root, using $x_0=1.5$, the successive iterates are $1.45386$, $1.45521$ which is the solution for six significant figures. Limiting to a single iteration, we should have obtained $$x \simeq \frac{6 \log \left(\frac{9}{8}\right) \log (6)-3 \log (384)}{3 \log
   ^2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\log (147456)}$$

For the second root, using $x_0=4.0$, the successive iterates are $3.91886$, $3.91689$ which is the solution for six significant figures. Limiting to a single iteration, we should have obtained $$x \simeq \frac{\log \left(\frac{4096}{81}\right)+\log (6) \log (64)}{\log ^2(4)+\log
   \left(\frac{8}{3}\right)}$$ As you can see, all of this could be done using a pocket calculator.

Comment: How did you evaluate $\log_{\sqrt{x}}2$ ? Seems to me that there's missing a factor $2$ in your equations (when compared with the other answer).

Comment: @HandeBruijn $$\log_{\sqrt{x}}a=\frac{\log (a)}{\log \left(\sqrt{x}\right)}=\frac{2 \log (a)}{\log (x)}$$ I double checked and I did not find anything wrong. Take care : some $\log(2)$ became $\log(4)$. Please tell me where I made mistakes. I really thank you for your attention. Cheers :-)

Comment: OK, now I see there's nothing wrong indeed (that $\log(4)$ as you say).

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the isn't solvable with Algebra II, unless you resort to the mess that is complex logs. However:
$$
log_\sqrt{x}2+log_6x^x=4\Rightarrow log_\sqrt{x}6+x(log_26)(log_6x)=4(log_26)\Rightarrow \frac{2}{log_6x}+x(log_26)(log_6x)=4(log_26)\Rightarrow2+x(log_6x)^2-4(log_6x)(log_26)=0
$$
which is a quadratic in $log_6x$ except for the pesky x coefficient. Using the quadratic formula anyway, and evaluating the logs,
$$
log_6x\approx\frac{10.34\pm\sqrt{106.91-8x}}{2x}
$$
This is definitely solvable. However, The only way I can come up with a numerical solution is graphing the two sides.